# jQuery noConflict mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I'm trying to use jQuery on a Joomla site, and Joomla loads jQuery in noConflict mode. I'm trying to wrap my code in `(function($){ ... })(jQuery);`.

This works:

```
function calculate()
{
    var de = document.calculator.de.value;
    var para = document.calculator.para.value;
    var quantia = document.calculator.quantia.value;
    var pais = jQuery("#para option:selected").text();
    var curr = (pais == "Brazil" ? "Reais" : "Euro");
    var tax = (pais == "Brazil" ? 0 : 3)
    result = Math.round(quantia * para) + ' ' + curr;
    jQuery('#result').text(result);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

This doesn't work (*Uncaught ReferenceError: calculate is not defined*):

```
(function($){
function calculate()
{
    var de = document.calculator.de.value;
    var para = document.calculator.para.value;
    var quantia = document.calculator.quantia.value;
    var pais = $("#para option:selected").text();
    var curr = (pais == "Brazil" ? "Reais" : "Euro");
    var tax = (pais == "Brazil" ? 0 : 3)
    result = Math.round(quantia * para) + ' ' + curr;
    $('#result').text(result);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
})(jQuery);
```

I'm probably missing a small detail, but where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `calculate` is local to the closure. The best solution would be putting *all* of your code into the closure. In case this is not possible you can assign the function to `window` via:

```
window.calculate = calculate;
```

You can also return it from the closure and then assign it to the `calculate` variable:

```
calculate = (function($) {
    ...
    return calculate;
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Great, that works. But if I have several functions, do I have to wrap each of them in a similar way, or can I somehow wrap everything at once? (The function `calculate` is called from here: `<input type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" name="submit" value="CALCULAR" onclick="calculate()" />`

Comment: @johanpw As you are already using jQuery: Simply bind a proper event listener. Read up about `jQuery.on`